# how I can submit a stored procedure that receives parameter within a stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I am currently doing a process, which requires submitting a stored procedure receives parameters within another stored procedure, this is the code that I am forming:

```
SET PARAMETROS1 = '''<root><esquema></esquema></root>''' ; 
SET PARAMETROS2 = '''CALL ' || ESQUEMAOR || '.PRU_LLAMA(''' || PARAMETROS1 || ''')''' ; 
SET SENTENCIA = '''SBMJOB CMD(CALL PGM(QZDFMDB2) PARM(' || PARAMETROS2 || ')) JOB(MIGRA14) JOBQ(QGPL/TEL)''' ; 
SET MAXLENGTH = LENGTH ( TRIM ( SENTENCIA ) ) ; 
SET MAXLENGTH = LENGTH ( SENTENCIA ) - 4 ; 
SET NUMERO = CAST ( MAXLENGTH AS VARCHAR ( 10 ) ) ; 
WHILE ( LENGTH ( NUMERO ) < 10 ) DO 
    SET NUMERO = '0' || NUMERO ; 
END WHILE ; 
SET STMT_QUERY = 'CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC(' || SENTENCIA || ' , ' || NUMERO || '.00000)' ; 
PREPARE STMT1 FROM STMT_QUERY ; 
EXECUTE STMT1 ;
```

and I make the following error:

> Keyword CALL not expected. Valid tokens: ) ,

**needs your help **

Comment: What SQL is this? Please update your Tags

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
EXECUTE spName Param1, ..., ParamN
```